# How to use ipcalc on CentOS?

Tags: centos

I'm trying to use `ipcalc` on CentOS 7.9 :

```bash
# ipcalc 10.69.69.68/27
Usage: ipcalc [OPTION...]
  -c, --check         Validate IP address for specified address family
  -4, --ipv4          IPv4 address family (default)
  -6, --ipv6          IPv6 address family
  -b, --broadcast     Display calculated broadcast address
  -h, --hostname      Show hostname determined via DNS
  -m, --netmask       Display default netmask for IP (class A, B, or C)
  -n, --network       Display network address
  -p, --prefix        Display network prefix
  -s, --silent        Don't ever display error messages

Help options:
  -?, --help          Show this help message
  --usage             Display brief usage message
```

It works differently on Ubuntu :

```bash
$ ipcalc 10.69.69.68/27
Address:   10.69.69.68          00001010.01000101.01000101.010 00100
Netmask:   255.255.255.224 = 27 11111111.11111111.11111111.111 00000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.31             00000000.00000000.00000000.000 11111
=>
Network:   10.69.69.64/27       00001010.01000101.01000101.010 00000
HostMin:   10.69.69.65          00001010.01000101.01000101.010 00001
HostMax:   10.69.69.94          00001010.01000101.01000101.010 11110
Broadcast: 10.69.69.95          00001010.01000101.01000101.010 11111
Hosts/Net: 30                    Class A, Private Internet

$
```

Comment: The help output seems pretty informative. What would you like to do? E.g., you can calculate the netmask from a CIDR spec by running `ipcalc --netmask 10.69.69.68/27` (which returns `NETMASK=255.255.255.224`).

Comment: @larsks It seems the `ipcalc [OPTION...]` options are not optional at all but mandatory in the `ipcalc` from `initscripts`package version on CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ipcalc` binary for CentOS 7.9 comes from the initscripts package whereas that of Ubuntu (I can't check all of the versions right now) and CentOS, RHEL, Almalinux, and Rocky Linux 8 and 9 are from the `ipcalc` package itself.

For that of CentOS 7.9, the closest that you can get to the output from Ubuntu is with the following:

```
ipcalc -nbmp 10.69.69.68/27
```

Output:

```
NETMASK=255.255.255.224
PREFIX=27
BROADCAST=10.69.69.68.95
NETWORK=10.69.69.64
```

`ipcalc`on CentOS 7 doesn't have the options to give the output that you are seeing on Ubuntu and it must be used with at least one of the options which is why you are getting what you have in your question.

The only option for getting what you see in Ubuntu is to build the minimum version of 0.2.3 from source and prepend it to your `PATH` and use that one instead.